# How can I paste text into Confluence without losing formatting?

Tags: confluence

I have some verbiage in a plain-text email that I would like to paste into a Confluence doc.

How can I do this without losing the formatting?  In particular, there are some columns of numbers aligned with spaces.  Pasting strips out all the spaces, so even if I specify a "preformatted" paragraph I've lost all alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Go to Insert
- Insert Wiki Markup
- Insert the following:

  {code}
  Your code here...
  {code}

SourceL https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12213/how-to-paste-code-properly-in-confluence-4

Comment: Note that this may not work if the pasted code is large or contains curly braces.